# Existe alguma maneira de obter informações sobre uma determinada rua?

Tags: google-maps

Minha questão é bem simples, utilizando a API do `google-maps` eu gostaria de obter as seguintes informações:

```
{
    Street: "Getulio vargas",
    Information:
    {
        { Distance: 120, Type: "School", Title: "Escola Estadual Caixas" },
        { Distance: 250, Type: "Market", Title: "Bahamas" },
        { Distance: 310, Type: "Restaurant", Title: "Casa Italia" },
        { Distance: 390, Type: "Hotel", Title: "Victory Suites" }
    },
    StreetCorner:
    {
        { Distance: 150, Direction: "Left", Name: "Rua das Flores" }
        { Distance: 370, Direction: "Right", Title: "Barbosa Lima" }
    }
}
```

Não sei se o `google-maps` tem alguma API que retorne esse tipo de informação, mas é "exatamente" esse tipo de informação que eu preciso.

Comment: Este exemplo você pegou de alguma aplicação ou construiu para mostrar quais dados você precisa? Outra coisa: como pretende fazer a consulta, irá informar também cidade/estado/país? Acredito que não exista, mas talvez seja possível combinar dados de várias fontes.

Comment: Construí para mostrar quais dados preciso. E sim, informaria todo o endereço. Quanto a combinar várias fontes, eu também não sei alternativas.

Comment: OK, só para saber mesmo se a busca não será tão genérica, a primeira parte, `Information`, o Google Places fornece, o problema é encontrar quais ruais cruzam com a que estamos querendo, tem a API nova do Maps, a `Roads`, não cheguei a procurar, mas se encontrar algo posto para você

Answer (score -2):

Sim, a função [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) faz o que você está precisando, e ainda retorna mais informações além dessas que você precisa. Estou supondo que você tem a latitude e longitude (elas são necessárias pra efetuar essa pesquisa).

Comment: O serviço de *geocoding* retorna estas informações, como o `StreetCorner`? Consegue incluir um exemplo? E não é preciso latitude/longitude, elas só são necessárias no *geocode* reverso

Comment: É exatamente esse meu problema, preciso de informações da "Rua" mesmo, não de um local.